# How to ungroup an object array based on multiple array properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Think of an object array, each of them having certain array properties like `versions`, `targets`. I want to ungroup objects for each `version` and `target`.

```
const myArray = [
  { 'name': 'a', versions: [1, 2], targets: ['server1', 'server2']},
  { 'name': 'b', versions: [], targets: ['server1', 'server2', 'server3']},
  { 'name': 'c', versions: [1], targets: []}
]
```

Desired output for `myArray` above would be:

```
[
  { 'name': 'a', version: 1,         target: 'server1'},
  { 'name': 'a', version: 1,         target: 'server2'},
  { 'name': 'a', version: 2,         target: 'server1'},
  { 'name': 'a', version: 2,         target: 'server2'},
  { 'name': 'b', version: undefined, target: 'server1'},
  { 'name': 'b', version: undefined, target: 'server2'},
  { 'name': 'b', version: undefined, target: 'server3'},
  { 'name': 'c', version: 1,         target: undefined},
]
```

I pondered using nested `for`/`forEach` loops, but am almost pretty sure there must be a more precise and reasonable way of achieving it built-in es6 functions or so. And that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: There isn't a native method that I know of off-the-bat: I guess that's because what you're seeing essentially is creating all possible combinations of versions + targets. That would call for a basic `for` loop, and it will grow in complexity the more dimensions you have, since the more nested the loops will have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.flatMap`:

```
  const notEmpty = arr => arr.length ? arr : [undefined];

  myArray.flatMap(({ name, versions, targets }) => notEmpty(versions).flatMap(version => notEmpty(targets).map(target => ({ name, version, target }))));
```

Or with more dimensions, generators get very useful:

```
  function* cartesian(obj, key, ...keys) {
     if(!key) {
         yield obj;
         return;
     }

    const { [key + "s"]: entries, ...rest } = obj;
    for(const entry of (entries.length ? entries : [undefined])) {
        yield* cartesian({ [key]: entry, ...rest }, ...keys);
     }
 }

 myArray.flatMap(it => cartesian(it, "version", "target"))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `it => Array.from(cartesian(...))`? Currently it returns a generator object. Also, rest parameter syntax here: `cartesian(obj, key, ...keys)`

Comment: A humble note about the generator function way: The the last command line in the function performing the recursion makes Typescript complain like `Expected 3 arguments, but got 1 or more.ts(2556) | An argument for 'key' was not provided`. Do not know if it is Typescript who does not support that notation or so. All in all, the question does not feature Typescript.

Comment: @adiga no, it's an iterator, and afaik `flatMap` can handle those. Oh, you're right with the parameters though

Comment: @vahdet nah, the root cause was a mistake of mine, this might work with the edit. However Typescript might be unable to type it correctly, it'll need annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method:

```
const result = myArray.reduce((a, {name, versions, targets}) => {
  versions.forEach((el, ind) => {
      a.push({name, version: versions[ind], target: targets[ind]})
  });
  targets.forEach((el, ind) => {
      a.push({name, version: versions[ind], target: targets[ind]})
  });  
  return a;    
}, []);
```

An example:

```js
const myArray = [
  { 'name': 'a', versions: [1, 2], targets: ['server1', 'server2']},
  { 'name': 'b', versions: [], targets: ['server1', 'server2', 'server3']},
  { 'name': 'c', versions: [1], targets: []}
]


const result = myArray.reduce((a, {name, versions, targets}) => {
  versions.forEach((el, ind) => {
      a.push({name, version: versions[ind], target: targets[ind]})
  });
  targets.forEach((el, ind) => {
      a.push({name, version: versions[ind], target: targets[ind]})
 });  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [
  { 'name': 'a', versions: [1, 2], targets: ['server1', 'server2'] },
  { 'name': 'b', versions: [], targets: ['server1', 'server2', 'server3'] },
  { 'name': 'c', versions: [1], targets: [] }
]

const reducer = (acc, current) => {
  const { name, versions, targets } = current;
  for (let i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    acc.push({ name, version: versions[i], target: targets[i] })
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    acc.push({ name, version: versions[i], target: targets[i] })
  }

  return acc;
}

const ungroup = array => array.reduce(reducer, [])

console.log(ungroup(myArray))
```

Comment: Its result contains duplicates like `{ "name": "a",  "version": 1,  "target": "server1" }`

Answer (score 0):

We can Un group the objects in the following way

```js
const rows = [
  {
"groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1579",
"clientName": "Apple",
"Id": 110117,
"manageFunds": [
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea53",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea54",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  }
],
"size": 2,
"bulkUploadErrorMessage": ""
  },
  {
"groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1589",
"clientName": "Mango",
"Id": 110118,
"manageFunds": [
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea55",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea56",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  }
],
"size": 2,
"bulkUploadErrorMessage": ""
  },
  {
"groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1599",
"clientName": "Orange",
"Id": 110119,
"manageFunds": [
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea57",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea58",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea59",
    "address": {
      "address1": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zipcode": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  }
],
"size": 3,
"bulkUploadErrorMessage": ""
  }
]

const mergeMF = input => {
const initObj = []
input.forEach(rootItem => {
    const { Id, clientName, manageFunds } = rootItem
    const groupId = rootItem.groupId
    manageFunds.forEach(subItem => {
        const newSubItem = {
            ...subItem,
            accountId: subItem.accountId,
            Id: Id,
            clientName: clientName,
            groupId: groupId,
        }
        initObj.push({
            checked: false,
            data: newSubItem,
            isCollapsed: false,
            validationErrors: subItem.errorMessages
        })
    })
})
return initObj
}

console.log(mergeMF(rows))
```